# image texture is not visible on object

Tags: uv, image

[image: image does not show up on object]

[image: nodes of false texturing]

I have problems with texturing the grey part of the calculator I have been working on recently. If I try to texture the same part of the model with an other picture it works perfectly well.

blender file: [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the .blend file will be nice to check the things out but when looking on the pictures I decided to try to **answer** You because I could NOT comment (newbie here).

At least You are using two different textures and probably also the materials for Your model so keep in mind that if U using more than one for one UV mesh *U have to ASSIGN the desired material with the desired faces!*

On the image below there could be seen top face assigned to the BLUE material and the rest to the RED material. So if U have some faces assigned to the material which works and not the crucial ones to the material with that "texas instruments" texture it could be a problem.

[image]

...if this is not that case then please try to provide us Your .blend file here so we all could check it and write You a solution buddy.

Sincerely, Jan

Comment: I have added the blender file to the initial post. I have already assigned the faces to the new material. I assume that the texture image itself is the reason for the problem, considering the fact, that other texture images are visible fpr the same material.

Comment: Ok, let me check the file today and I will let U know (hope shortly)...

Comment: Lennart, PLZ include **all textures** into the .blend file!

Comment: I have added all used textures to the file. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5314" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5314/)

Answer (score 0):

So here is the image of the NODES with the final result...

[image]

...as U could see I add a new material with a new logo texture I made so feel free to check the scene file provided buddy ;).

Sincerely, Jan

[image]